# Spring boot application - how to show the dependency JAR version used in actuator info endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependencies, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring boot project that uses a few simple java lib jar files as dependency. Few of these jar files are updated frequently.

I want to add the dependency jar version information to the actuator info endpoint so that at any point, I can see what version of library given build of the project using.

Can anyone provide some guidance on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic answer to build a solution you are asking for, because a spring boot application might be packaged in different ways for runtime.
For example it might be an executable jar like it is described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html) or it might be an OCI image packaged by [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/).

Depending on the format, there are alternative ways to retrieve classpath library versions like `classpath.idx` from executable jar or `jib-classpath-file` from [jib-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib) created images.

But if you have a stable environment and if you know, where you can get the information from, then you should start writing a spring bean with `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint` annotation, which exposes the information parsed from those files.